# DTD syntax for SQL UNIQUE constraint

Tags: sql, xml, xsd, dtd, idref

I am moving from accessing data via a database to XML for my application specific needs. I am currently writing a DTD for the XML by referring to my SQL table schema. I have defined a constraint on 4 columns to be unique(These 4 columns defines a directory structure 3 step deep so together they have to be unique eg. dir1/dir2/dir3/dirA and dir1/dir2/dir3/dirB). I know I can use an ID to maintain uniqueness of an attribute, but how can I bind this for 4 attributes together?

Thanks,

Shripad

Comment: Side question: any reason you chose a DTD over an XSD?

Comment: We are using DTD for defining a schema for another application, other than that I don't have specific reason.

Comment: Hmm I think using XSD is quite straightforward; I will give it a try.
Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ID` along with an `IDREF` to define this relationship. Here are two formats:

**DTD**

```
  <!DOCTYPE lab_group [
  <!ELEMENT lab_group (student_name)*>
  <!ELEMENT student_name (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST student_name student_no ID #REQUIRED>
  <!ATTLIST student_name tutor_1 IDREF #IMPLIED>
  <!ATTLIST student_name tutor_2 IDREF #IMPLIED>
  <!ATTLIST student_name tutor_3 IDREF #IMPLIED>
  <!ATTLIST student_name tutor_4 IDREF #IMPLIED>
  ]>
```

**XSD**

```
  <xs:element name="student_name">
   <xs:key name="ID">
     <xs:selector xpath="student_no"/>
     <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
   </xs:key>
   <xs:keyref name="IDREF" refer="ID">
     <xs:selector xpath="//student_name/@tutor_1|//student_name/@tutor_2|//student_name/@tutor_3|//student_name/@tutor_4"/>
     <xs:field xpath="@ref"/>
   </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>
```

Here are a few analogues for quick reference:

- ID => primary key
- IDREF => foreign key
- IDREFS => joins